# can I modify cnf file while database is running?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that needs a new Innodb file.  I understand that the database needs to be shutdown, the cnf modified and the database restarted.  There's currently a process in place that shutsdown the database for a nightly coldbackup.  My question is, can I modify the cnf file now, while the database is up and expect the restart later this evening to pick up the change?

Answer (score 3):

Sure -- MySQL doesn't write to the config file. Just make sure to be around when the restart happens to make sure it comes back up properly with the new configuration!